# I need powershell script to replace the content of a file path that is subject to change

Tags: powershell

I wrote a shell scrip below for replace the path and it worked. But my problem is the (Solana July Release) is subject to change. It can be anything like (Solana December Release) or (Solana April Release and hotfix). I need help with how to use something like wildcard or anything to replace that part so that I don't have to be making modifications each time I want to use the script. FYI, The content of the file is written like this

```
$logFile = "C:\\Windows Powershell\\_SolanaDBUpgradeAsync\\Solana July Release\\Solana Staging\\SolanaDBUpgradeLog_DB01_20211215.txt"


$Path01 = "C:\Windows Powershell\_SolanaDBUpgradeAsync\Solana $Current_Month Release\Solana Staging\Stagingdb01-$Current_Month`Sync"
(Get-Content $Path01) -replace ("C:\\Windows Powershell\\_SolanaDBUpgradeAsync\\Solana July Release\\Solana Staging\\SolanaDBUpgradeLog_DB01_20211215.txt","C:\Windows Powershell\_SolanaDBUpgradeAsync\$newmonth\Solana Staging\SolanaDBUpgradeLog_DB01_$dateFormat.txt") | Set-Content $Path01 -Force
```

Comment: Do these paths refer to the local file system? You could discover the name by simply resolving `C:\Windows PowerShell\_SolanaDBUpgradeAsync\Solana * Release`, but what should happen if multiple such folders are found?

Comment: The file path is this "C:\Windows Powershell\_SolanaDBUpgradeAsync\Solana $Current_Month Release\Solana Staging\Stagingdb01-$Current_Month`Sync" . when i edit the file with say text editor, it contains this,    $logFile = "C:\\Windows Powershell\\_SolanaDBUpgradeAsync\\Solana July Release\\Solana Staging\\SolanaDBUpgradeLog_DB01_20211215.txt",
  . So assuming i run the script now, the new content will reflect January as current month. Then if i want to run it say next month, i have to go and modify my script so that part Solana July release will be changed to Solana January Release

Comment: And you need help generating the correct month name for `$Current_Month`?

Comment: I already have $Current_Month, i just need the one for the Solana July Release or Solana (previous month used) release